# c++ unsigned infinite loop comparison bug

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer

Noticed a bug in one of the programs I was working on, extracted the code, and it's basically this.
It does an unsigned comparison to a signed int and results in an infinite loop:

```
#include <iostream>  

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000)
    {
        printf("%o\n", i);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using this instead:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    unsigned int i = 0;
    while (i < 1000000u)
    {
        printf("%o\n", i);
        ++i;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which I thought would fix the signed/unsigned comparison, and it doesn't, it's still hitting an infinite loop. So I also tried casting it to unsigned int, and no dice, still infinite loops.

Using Visual Studio 2015, full optimization, release compiler.

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop? This looks like a very long loop to me, especially since printing takes significant time. Change to `i += 1000` to see if the exit condition works.

Comment: This is not a problem of signed/unsigned comparison. The value `1000000` is in both ranges, and you tried solving the problem supposing that this is the reason of it, but it did not work.

Comment: Why do you `#include <iostream>` but then use `printf`?

Comment: Just as a reference: The first program works as expected(Print numbers) with gcc 5.3.1 on 64bit linux. Are you sure there is a problem, and not just a slow printf ?

Comment: they were using cout in the original code, which was much slower....testing purposes mainly, printf is leagues faster for testing

Comment: @MTilsted it does work on gcc for me, using mingw, it doesn't work on the VC++ compiler

Comment: I can't change the compiler though for the corporate project, which is much larger than this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I can not reproduce the infinite loop on Win7 nor Ubuntu (both 64-bit) I believe the problem is your printf() function with unsigned octal number representation which leads you to think it enters an infinite loop. Changing the `%o` parameter to `%u` might clarify the issue.

Comment: Huh, apparently that's true, std::cout << std::oct << n << '\n' also modifies the base integer to octal, which is what they were using originally

Answer (score 1):

This is because int type overflow. See the type [limits](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/climits/).  For such a huge number comparison you should use `long` instead `int`

Comment: Maybe, but `int` is at least 32bits on most platforms these days.

Comment: Unlikely to be the case. The OP mentioned VS 2015, where the default int type is 32-bit, far wider than `1000000` requires.

Comment: and its 64-bit compiled on VC++, it does print the numbers, it just doesn't stop, til it does hit the limit; and then because of unsigned rules, it still doesn't stop, it just starts over

Comment: @BrianDeragon `unsigned int` is *still* 32-bit in VC++ 2015, even for a 64-bit compile.

Comment: `long` is often the same size as `int`. For large numbers you probably should not assume anything and instead just use a type guaranteed to have a certain minimum size; they exist for a reason. However, this size problem is not an issue to begin with given a 32-bit unsigned integer type, which you can sort of assume as the norm for visual studio 2015.